# "Permission Access on Suite-let External Link"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can I get access Suite-let externally without login into NETSUITE..

I am trying to get Employee record through suitelet but internally it is showing employee records but when I get external link it send me error message

> "You do not have permission to access Employee data"

```js
///Search for employee record////
var mySearch = search.create({
        type: record.Type.EMPLOYEE,
        columns: ['entityid','salutation','email','mobilephone'],
        filters: [
            ['supervisor', 'is', 8316]
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Script Deployment, change the value of `Execute as Role` to a role that has permission on Employees.

[image]